# ASP.NET MVC: Routing hierarchy URL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-routing

How can I make routing for this?

URL: **/category/main/sub/** or **/category/main/sub1/subsub/**

I want to have **/main/sub/** and **/main/sub1/subsub/** as parameters in Index action method of CategoryController.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer:

Should use "/category/{*path}" instead of "/category/{path}" in the routing path.